# Android Bluetooth: Update connection state dynamically for single row in listview

Tags: android, listview, bluetooth, onclicklistener, gatt

I would like to create a listview with all bluetooth devices scanned. Each row will contain a connection state of text and clicking it will make the device connect to remote device. How could I update only the single row of remote device being connected in listview so the connection state will keep changing: disconnected -> connecting -> connected for example?

1. Update single row only so the row object needs to be passed to updater somehow?
2. State needs to keep changing so I need to create a customized listener?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take row from ListView at required position and update:

```
private void refreshConnectionState(int rowIndex, String newConnectionState){
    View row = devicesListView.getChildAt(rowIndex);
    if(row == null) return;

    TextView stateTextView = (TextView )row.findViewById(R.id.state_text_view);       
    stateTextView.setText(newConnectionState);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Sergey! Does that mean that when specific row is clicked, I will need to find its index and store in global variable?

Comment: No. You can take row index from your adapter by device id

Comment: Actually here's somewhere I am still confused about. Should I always call refreshConnectionState from caller who changed the state? And if the state is changing dynamically, how can the caller always know this row index?

Comment: Your custom adapter should contain _serachDeviceById_. And "devices" provider should call refresh method from adapter, when devices set or device state changed. I think this works :)

Comment: I see what you mean now. Thanks Sergey and will give it a try!